# What's the best way to learn server RESTful code?

Tags: rest, https, opensocial

I'm an experienced client application developer (C++/C#), but need to come up to speed quickly on writing server side code to perform RESTful interactions.  Specifically, I need to learn how to exchange data with OpenSocial containers via the RESTful API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RESTful Web Services](http://www.crummy.com/writing/RESTful-Web-Services/)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a book out on this.  Will definitely buy.

Comment: The original dissertation (http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) that Darrell Miller mentioned is also really good. It will help you understand the reasoning behind a lot the things described in the book. That way you have a better feel for edgecases that aren't covered in-book

Comment: @Hank yes, that's the authoritative source on REST.

Answer (score 5):

The [RESTWiki](http://rest.blueoxen.net/cgi-bin/wiki.pl) is a very good resource and then there is the classic ["How I explained  REST to my Wife"](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife).

However, don't forget to go read about it directly from the [source](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm), it is not as difficult a read as it may first seem.

And I am assuming you will be doing REST over HTTP so [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) will come in very handy.

Lastly, considering OpenSocial supports the Atom Publishing Protocol, [this](http://ietfreport.isoc.org/idref/draft-ietf-atompub-protocol/) will be useful.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [this](http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html) to be a good introduction to RESTful web apps, although it doesn't refer to OpenSocial containers.

Comment: Good overview doc.  Here's another reference with some motivation behing RESTful (http://ajaxpatterns.org/RESTful_Service).